# Why moment isValid() API does not support format 'L' for non 'en' local

Tags: momentjs

Moment API isValid seems only support format 'L' for local is 'en':

**locale set to 'en':**

```
moment(new Date()).locale('en').format('L')              //"04/27/2016"
moment('04/27/2016', 'L', true).isValid()                //true
```

**local set to 'zh-cn':**

```
moment(new Date()).locale('zh-cn').format('L')           //"2016-04-27"
moment('2016-04-27', 'L', true).isValid()                //false, why here is false?
```

As i don't want to hard code 'MM-DD-YYYY' for 'zh-cn' here, is there any other good way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the locale like that only affects the current instance of `moment`, not any future instances. Future instances use the default locale again, which in your case means `'L'` is not the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

You can either set the locale globally:

```
moment.locale('zh-cn');
moment(new Date()).format('L')            // 2016-04-27
moment('2016-04-27', 'L', true).isValid() // true
```

Or specify the locale for each instance, including the one you use for parsing:

```
moment(new Date()).locale('zh-cn').format('L')     // 2016-04-27
moment('2016-04-27', 'L', 'zh-cn', true).isValid() // true
```